How do I make the hair particles not go through other object?
How can I make these hairs not go further than the object? (So that its not on the black part)
I have tried trimming, but it changes the whole hair texture.
I am trying to obtain this:


These are my settings:

Please let me know if you need more information
Tia

Do you want to cut them?

@Blunder -- similar question

Yes I am trying to cut them shorter :) but also that it doesn't offset I think

Is that a cut edge of a felt mat? It's a bit hard to see in your screenshot (the model). You can cut the curve with Geometry Nodes. But I don't think it will help you if it's a felt mat. Your settings are a bit off. The hair is 4mm long but the curl radius is 8 cm? And you have 600 control points for each curve! The offset could come from the noise. But I think the main issue is the shrink warp. It would be better to do a flat projection. You also have not defined a Density Mask or a Mask Texture to define where the hairs should be. Is this intended?

Hey So I was trying to follow a tutorial. It indeed is a felt mat. I think I better try starting over again. Thank you!
